# how to multiple insert and delete using foreach

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

Hi i'm newbie in php foreach, i want to loop insert and delete data in mysql using foreach.

Here's my code

```
<?php function _invite() { 
    $fi = $_POST['fi'];
    if ($_POST['SUPDATE']) {
        // validasi
        // jika valid :
            $fi['nim']=1111,222,333; // from input
            $ex = explode(',',$fi['nim']);

            $sql1 = "DELETE FROM bea_siswaundangan WHERE idbeasiswa='".$_GET['id']."' AND";
            $sql2 = "INSERT INTO bea_siswaundangan (nim,tahun,tgl_input,idbeasiswa) VALUES";
            foreach ($ex as $value) {
             $sql1 .= "nim='".$value."'";
             $sql2 .= "('".$value."','".$fi['tahun']."',now(),'".$_GET['id']."')";
            }
            $sql1=rtrim($sql1, ',');
            $sql2=rtrim($sql2, ',');
            mysql_query($sql1);
            mysql_query($sql2);
            echo'sql1='.$sql1.' dan sql2='.$sql2.'';
            // redirect ke _view -> pake javascript aja
            ?>

            <?php
        // else

            // tampilkan pesan error

    }
    _forminvite($fi);
}?>
```

The output will be like this

```
DELETE FROM bea_siswaundangan WHERE idbeasiswa='1' AND nim='111'nim='222'nim='3333'
```

but what i want is

```
DELETE FROM bea_siswaundangan WHERE idbeasiswa='1' AND nim='1111'
DELETE FROM bea_siswaundangan WHERE idbeasiswa='1' AND nim='2222'
DELETE FROM bea_siswaundangan WHERE idbeasiswa='1' AND nim='1111'
```

How to do like what i want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the beginning of query in another variable, then concat it with $sql1

```
$sql1_begin = "DELETE FROM bea_siswaundangan WHERE idbeasiswa='".$_GET['id']."' AND ";
$sql1 = '';

foreach ($ex as $value) {
    $sql1 .= $sql1_begin."nim='".$value."'; ";
    $sql2 .= "('".$value."','".$fi['tahun']."',now(),'".$_GET['id']."')";
}
```

**Edit :** To delete with one query, do like this

```
$nim = array();
foreach ($ex as $value) {
    $nim[] = "'".$value."'";
    $sql2 .= "('".$value."','".$fi['tahun']."',now(),'".$_GET['id']."')";
}

$sql1 = "DELETE FROM bea_siswaundangan WHERE idbeasiswa='".$_GET['id']."' AND nim IN (".implode(',', $nim).")";
```

Comment: thanks @mario, like what i want, but how to execute the query
mysql_query looks like 
"DELETE FROM bea_siswaundangan WHERE idbeasiswa='1' AND nim='111'DELETE FROM bea_siswaundangan WHERE idbeasiswa='1' AND nim='222'DELETE FROM bea_siswaundangan WHERE idbeasiswa='1' AND nim='333'
and how to execute that ?
thanks before... :)

Comment: add the `";"` after `$value`

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented your code and it works well

```
            foreach ($ex as $value) {

            $sql1 = "DELETE FROM bea_siswaundangan WHERE idbeasiswa='".$_GET['id']."' AND nim='".$value."'";
            $sql2 = "INSERT INTO bea_siswaundangan (nim,tahun,tgl_input,idbeasiswa) VALUES ('".$value."','".$fi['tahun']."',now(),'".$_GET['id']."')";
           }
            mysql_query($sql1);
            mysql_query($sql2);
            echo'sql1='.$sql1.' dan sql2='.$sql2.'';
            ?>

            <?php
    }
    _forminvite($fi);
}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the implode function to avoid the need for a loop.

Something liek this:-

```
<?php 
function _invite() 
{ 
    $fi = $_POST['fi'];
    $id = intval($_GET['id']);
    if ($_POST['SUPDATE']) 
    {
        // validasi
        // jika valid :
        $fi['nim']=1111,222,333; // from input
        $ex = explode(',',$fi['nim']);

        $sql1 = "DELETE FROM bea_siswaundangan WHERE idbeasiswa=$id AND nim IN ('".implode("','", $ex)."')";
        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO bea_siswaundangan (nim, tahun, tgl_input, idbeasiswa) VALUES ('".implode("','".$fi['tahun']."',NOW(),$id),('", $ex)."','".$fi['tahun']."',NOW(),$id)";
        mysql_query($sql1);
        mysql_query($sql2);
        echo'sql1='.$sql1.' dan sql2='.$sql2.'';
        // redirect ke _view -> pake javascript aja
        // else

        // tampilkan pesan error

    }
    _forminvite($fi);
}
?>
```

Note this is assuming that you have sanitised $fi['tahun']